# Python azure.storage.filedatalake - InvalidHeaerValue

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to simply append a CSV file to a container on Azure Datalake, and I have the following class to do it:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from datetime import datetime


class AzureHandler:

    ###
    # CONSTRUCTOR AzureHandler
    ###
    def __init__(self, storage_account, storage_key):
        connect_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + \
            storage_account + ";AccountKey=" + storage_key + \
            ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
        self.datalake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(
            conn_str=connect_string)

    def write_tag_csv_file(self, container, folder_name, file_name, data):
        filename_to_write = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')+'_'+file_name
        file_system_client = self.datalake_service_client.get_file_system_client(
        container)
        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(folder_name)

        try:
            file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(filename_to_write)
            file_client.get_file_properties().size
            filesize_previous = file_client.get_file_properties().size
            file_client.append_data(
                data, offset=filesize_previous, length=len(data))
            file_client.flush_data(filesize_previous+len(data))
        except:
            file_client = directory_client.create_file(file_name)
            filesize_previous = 0
            file_client.append_data(
                data, offset=filesize_previous, length=len(data))
            file_client.flush_data(filesize_previous+len(data))
```

However, whenever I can **AzureHandler.write_tag_csv_file** I get a few of the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\python39\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\filedatalake\_data_lake_file_client.py", line 450, in append_data
    return self._client.path.append_data(**options)
  File "C:\python39\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\filedatalake\_generated\operations\_path_operations.py", line 1617, in append_data
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidHeaderValue) The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
```

I tried to read up a bit and saw it might be an API version issue, so I tried all available API versions by specifying them where I declare my datalake_service_client, but all of them give me the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: I tried your code and it can work fine. My API version is `12.2.3` ,python version is `3.8` .You can have a try.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct, I can run it without any error, the append operation is working well for `.csv` file.

Please try to install `the latest version of ADLS Gen2 package 12.2.3` here: [azure-storage-file-datalake 12.2.3](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake/). You can use this command to install it: `pip install azure-storage-file-datalake==12.2.3`, and no need to specifying the `api_version` where you declare my datalake_service_client.

Please let me know if you still have the issue. And also provide the detailed code how do you call this method.